# Finding the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions for a fourth order boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I am to find the nonpositive eigenvalues and eigenfunctions for the problem

$y^{(4)} + \lambda y = 0$

with the boundary conditions

$y(0) = y'(0) = 0$, $y(L) = y'(L) = 0$.

With some analysis, I can determine that $\lambda = 0$ is not an eigenvalue. However, for the case that $\lambda < 0$, I am having trouble determining the eigenvalues.

Using the general solution to the differential equation

$y_{gen} = c_1e^{\lambda^{\frac{1}{4}}x} + c_2e^{-\lambda^{\frac{1}{4}}x} + c_3\sin{(\lambda^{\frac{1}{4}}x)} + c_4\cos{(\lambda^{\frac{1}{4}}x)}$,

I should be able to determine a system of four equations for the constants. However, I become stuck at that point, and I am not sure the four equations are right

Answer (score 1):

With $\lambda=-k^4 \land \lambda<0$ we get the general solution

$$y(x)=c_1 e^{k x}+c_2 e^{-k x}+c_3 \sin (k x)+c_4 \cos (k x)$$

For the given boundary conditions we get the equations
$$y(0)=c_1+c_2+c_4=0$$
$$y'(0)=c_1 k-c_2 k+c_3 k=0$$
$$y(L)=c_1 e^{k L}+c_2 e^{-k L}+c_4 \cos (k L)+c_3 \sin (k L)=0$$
$$y'(L)=c_1 k e^{k L}-c_2 k e^{-k L}+c_3 k \cos (k L)-c_4 k \sin (k L)=0$$

We have a system of linear equations of the form $A\cdot c=0$ where $c=(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4)^T$ with

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 k & -k & k & 0 \\
 e^{k L} & e^{-k L} & \sin (k L) & \cos (k L) \\
 k e^{k L} & k \left(-e^{-k L}\right) & k \cos (k L) & -k \sin (k L) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$det(A)=-4 k^2 (\cos (k L) \cosh (k L)-1)=0$$

The eigenvalues $k_{i}$ must satisfy $\cos (k_{i} L) \cosh (k_{i} L)-1=0$ in order to get a nontrivial solution.

Numerically we can find some eigenvalues depending on $L$, here $L=1$: $$k\approx (4.730040744862704,7.853204624095838,10.99560783800167,14.13716549125746,...)$$

We get the Matrix $B$ by substitution $B=A|_{\cos(k L)=\text{sech}(k L),\sin(k L)=\pm\sqrt{1-\text{sech}(k L)^2}}$

$$\implies det(B)=0, rank(B)=3$$

**1st** solution for $\sin(k L)=+\sqrt{1-\text{sech}(k L)^2}$:

$$\left\{c_2\to -\frac{c_1 e^{k L} \left(e^{k L}-\sqrt{1-\text{sech}^2(k L)}-\text{sech}(k L)\right)}{e^{k L} \sqrt{1-\text{sech}^2(k L)}-e^{k L} \text{sech}(k L)+1},c_3\to \frac{c_1 \left(e^{2 k L}-2 e^{k L} \text{sech}(k L)+1\right)}{-e^{k L} \sqrt{1-\text{sech}^2(k L)}+e^{k L} \text{sech}(k L)-1},c_4\to -\frac{c_1 \left(-e^{2 k L}+2 e^{k L} \sqrt{1-\text{sech}^2(k L)}+1\right)}{e^{k L} \sqrt{1-\text{sech}^2(k L)}-e^{k L} \text{sech}(k L)+1}\right\}$$

**2nd** solution for $\sin(k L)=-\sqrt{1-\text{sech}(k L)^2}$:

$$\left\{c_2\to \frac{c_1 e^{k L} \left(e^{k L}+\sqrt{1-\text{sech}^2(k L)}-\text{sech}(k L)\right)}{e^{k L} \sqrt{1-\text{sech}^2(k L)}+e^{k L} \text{sech}(k L)-1},c_3\to -\frac{c_1 \left(-e^{2 k L}+2 e^{k L} \text{sech}(k L)-1\right)}{e^{k L} \sqrt{1-\text{sech}^2(k L)}+e^{k L} \text{sech}(k L)-1},c_4\to -\frac{c_1 \left(e^{2 k L}+2 e^{k L} \sqrt{1-\text{sech}^2(k L)}-1\right)}{e^{k L} \sqrt{1-\text{sech}^2(k L)}+e^{k L} \text{sech}(k L)-1}\right\}$$

Now you may plug in the solution(s) into $y(x)$ and substitute $k=k_{i}$ and you have the eigenfunction of $k_{i}$ (1st solution applies to even $i$, 2nd solution applies to odd $i$).

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth solution. As a final question, how do we know that varying L will not change the existence of nontrivial solutions?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't make clear that the eigenvalues depend on L.